# How to get timestamp from encrypted pdf (pdfbox, java)

Tags: java, encryption, digital-signature, pdfbox, trusted-timestamp

I have to create a function that tells me is an uploaded PDF file encrypted-only, timestamped-only, none, or both.
So far I am using PDFBox 2.0.5 and only success knowing timestamped-only and none file.

Here is the current code:

```
try{
    InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(file.getBytes());
    PDDocument d = PDDodument.load(fis); //encrypted file will go to InvalidPasswordException error
    //***file not encrypted***
    List<PDSignature> a = d.getSignatureDictionaries();
    List<PDSignatureField> b = d.getSignatureFields();
    if(a.size()==0 && b.size()==0){
        //***file not timestamped***
    }else{
        //***file timestamped***
    }
} catch(InvalidPasswordException e){
    //***file encrypted***
    //***is file timestamped?***
    //***is file not timestamped?***
} catch(IOException e){
}
```

My question is, how to know if there any timestamp (as signature) on encrypted pdf file?

Note: I have found several PDFBox usage example but rarely find PDFBox latest version implemented example

**Update note**: file is an uploaded MultipartFile object, having hard time getting its path avoiding copying or transferring it into another object type

Comment: Do you have the password / private key for decrypting the encrypted documents?

Comment: @mkl unfortunately the function wouldnt know each pdf password, I hope 
 it is possible to get through it without password though

Comment: You can call `PDDocument.load(file.getBytes());` that is more efficient. I have some code for the timestamps but it looks quite crazy, it is based on http://www.massapi.com/source/maven/20/11/2011209121/maven2/br/net/woodstock/rockframework/rockframework-security/3.0.0/rockframework-security-3.0.0-sources.jar/rockframework-security-3.0.0-sources.jar.unzip/br/net/woodstock/rockframework/security/sign/impl/BouncyCastlePKCS7Signer.java.html#286 so I'll wait if somebody has anything better.

Comment: Do also call isEncrypted(), pdf files may have an empty user password but non empty owner password, this is for restricted rights. And there can be signatures without timestamps.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr that would be great if I could use isEncrypted(), but I cant even construct object without getting password false error from a temporary multipartfile type of object

Comment: I meant call `isEncrypted()` after you were able to open a file without getting exception. At the place where you wrote `***file not encrypted***`.